# Help with producing a circuit that costs 17, then 9

Tags: circuit-design, cost

I'm am completely stuck on this question:

***We want to design a circuit that determines if a four-bit number is less than 10 and is also even.***

***a. (10 points) Write an expression of M such that M=1 if the four-bit number X (x3 x2 x1 x0) is less than 10
and is also even.***

***b. (20 points) Using only NOT gates, AND gates, and OR gates, show that the cost of the circuit you
produced in part a can be implemented with a cost of 17.***

***c. (15 points) After further inquiry, we have determined that it is not strictly necessary that M=1 in order
to determine if X matches our criteria. Write the expression for M̅, the complement of M.***

***d. (15 points) Draw the circuit which implements M̅, using only NOT, AND, and OR gates. Show that the
cost of the circuit produced in part c is 9.***

Ok so I did part ***a*** and got this formula: f(X3,X2,X1,X0) = X3'X0' + X2'X1'X0'.

I had M = (0, 2, 4, 6, 8), which is where I got the above equation from.

My problem is that in part ***b***, I keep getting a cost of 18, not 17. I even used a [digital logic calculator](http://www.32x8.com/) to help figure it out, but no matter what, even adding the 10 or removing the 0 and such, I can never get a cost of 17.

I can't even get a cost of 9 for part ***d***.

Is there a typo in this problem or something? How is a cost of 9 even possible? Did I do this problem incorrectly? I've spent so much time on it and tried every possible solution, but I cannot get a cost of 17 or 9.

***EDIT: the cost is calculated as follows, example: a 2 input AND gate would have a cost of 3 (2 inputs, plus the gate itself). Not gates have a cost of 2 (one gate plus one input). So for part b, I keep getting a cost of 18 because of 4 NOT gates = 8, one AND gate with 3 inputs, and one AND gate with 2 inputs = 7, and one OR gate with 2 inputs = 3, therefore 8 + 7 + 3 = 18.***

Comment: What definition of "cost" is this problem using?

Comment: @duskwuff the cost is calculated as follows, example: a 2 input AND gate would have a cost of 3 (2 inputs, plus the gate itself). Not gates have a cost of 2 (one gate plus one input).

So for part b, I keep getting a cost of 18 because of 4 NOT gates = 8, one AND gate with 3 inputs, and one AND gate with 2 inputs = 7, and one OR gate with 2 inputs = 3, therefore 8 + 7 + 3 = 18.

Comment: I don't know. It looks like two OR, one AND, one NOT, to me. Or two AND, one OR, and one NOT. That costs 11, right?

Answer (score 1):

the simplest I can manage using 2 input gates is 11

associative rule

X3'X0' + X2'X1'X0'  =  (X3' + X2'X1')X0'

Now apply de Morgan's theorem repeatedly.

M = (X3'+(X2+X1)') X0'

M = (X3(X2+X1))' X0'

M = ((X3(X2+X1))+X0)'

for a cost of 11

but the complement  M' = (X3(X2+X1))+X0)

for a cost of 9.

Comment: Another way I like to see things is to realize that you get lots of free NOT gates when you switch from an AND to an OR, or visa versa.

Comment: with the NOT gate at the end the cost is 11 :/

Comment: ah yes, I missed the part where M' was used instead of M

Comment: Best you can do is 11.